# Store state within the React Router component?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Ok, I'm pretty new to React in some ways and I am working on a simple react app that's 3 pages. I'm using `react-router`, partially so I can learn to use it.

On one page, I have a form that sets some state. The state obviously does not persist when you go to another route, because `react-router` renders a different component.

**Solution #1**

A solution is to have the main "App" component render one of the 3 pages/components (looking up the current route with params) and just store state there.

**Solution #2**

Another solution that seems obvious is storing the state in the Router component along with all the methods to update the state.

Then, I could just pass down the methods to update state to the components in the router.  Seemed like a good idea, but I cannot seem to find anything online about anyone doing anything like that.

I see a lot of `redux`, but that's overkill for what I am doing.

So, is that possible?  If it is, is there some reason that I cannot find anything about it? (Am I missing some terrible security thing or other gotchas that doing this would create.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of redux, i think you can also try react context. [Ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)

You can create a context in you App component and wrap your 3 page components in Context Provider to access the context. You can pass a map while creating a context, with values and setter,getter methods and use that map to change the values in your context map.
You can watch [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u0slAvqjA6E) talk for better understanding.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. This seems much more straight forward for what I'm developing for the size of the project. Given how limited it will be I know Redux is more than I need.

Answer (score 0):

Redux is what you need. Check this below approach as well.

App component

```
class App extends Component {
  state= {
     test: 'test'
  };

  render() {
        return (
        <Route path="/" component={() => {<Home {...this.state.test}/>}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Mmm.  I'll try that other approach you suggested. I know I can manage state using a higher component, it just seemed like the Router (already being the highest one) would make sense to store state.